# One Group Policy Folder cannot be accessed by only one single user

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

One of our Active Directory Users is not able to access one specific group policy folder. He receives a message like: "\DOMAIN\SYSVOL\DOMAIN\Policies\GPO ID" cannot be accessed. He is able to access every other group policy.

Here is a Screenshot of the Error message (in German):

[image]

I think because of this, we receive the error: "INFO: This user dies not have RSoP-Data." on running gpresult /h result.html.

Can anyone tell me what to do in this situation? I was not able to find any answer on google for this.

Regards